# How can I make thicker interior door slabs work as replacements for thinner slabs?

Tags: doors, interior

I screwed up when ordering new door slabs. Measured everything except the thickness, and, of course, I wasn't lucky.

Anyway, the door is pre-mortised, and it won't close because it is too thick. I am trying to figure out the best way to proceed given the fact that it is pre-mortised and with the holes for lock-sets.

Can I simply trim the door stop with a circular saw or a router? If not, what other options do I have?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't (practically speaking) make your slabs thinner. It would be a monumental undertaking considering the nature of hollow-core doors and symmetrical mortising. You can either move the stops or get new slabs and start over.

To move the stops, slice the paint with a utility knife, then work a steel putty knife behind the stop to loosen it. Gently pry the stop loose. Sand, fill, and paint the jambs.

Determine whether the stops are salvageable with sanding and repainting. Reinstall using trim nails and filler, and apply a final coat of paint.

Comment: The door IS too thick. It was supposed to be 1-3/8 but I ordered 1-3/4's. the reason I screwed up was because the Home Depot form didn't even have the 1-3/8 option so I neglected to check. I guess they are not so rare anymore.

Anyway, there are two problems with popping door stops. One is: there are no obvious nail holes or anything like that. They could be covered by multiple layers of paint but I just want to make sure the door stops aren't somehow part of the frame (my terminology may be off).

Comment: The second one is: The door stops extend beneath the floor. I presume, the doors were installed before the hardwood. Moving the whole thing is therefore problematic. I guess I would have to cut the door stops at the floor level.

Comment: @freevillage - oh so many problems. Use your 1-3/4" door to make a table and then go back and order the correct thickness door. It is really dumb to look for a way to kludge in a wrong thickness door. Time to bite the bullet and do it right.

Comment: Ordering new doors is not an option. I said I had used a Home Depot form but I did not order the doors at Home Depot, and I ordered more than one. 

I agree that I have to do something with door stops. I am looking for someone to help me with the plan and the selection of the tool.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on where your door is hitting the frame. If the problem is on the latch side of the door, the top, or the bottom, trimming it back a fraction of an inch using a table saw or hand plane may work. In particular, you may need to level the latch edge of the door a bit so its inner corner clears the frame.

If the problem is the stops, then either you need to re-sent the hinges so the door stands a bit proud or trim the stops back. The latter is probably necessary if you care about having the latch hardware line up.

The right approach in this case is to remove the stops, close the door to where it should be, and then install stops against the door's actual position; this is what I did when constructing a new doorframe for my basement door. But this presumes a frame where the stops can be removed; if it's a metal frame with integral stops you must fit the door to the frame.

(Alternatively, for wooden stops, you might be able to carefully trim them back in place. Harder to get right, harder to do a clean job especially if you don't have experience with making a clean trim to a straight line, and probably a lot more work.)

If you do need to give up and get another door, you may be able to find a buyer for the mis-sized one, or recover some of your money by donating it to somewhere like Habitat for Humanity's Re/Stores and claiming a tax credit. I helped a neighbor unload three very pretty unused doors that way, recovering about a third of their original price; much better than nothing and it put the doors in the hands of someone who would appreciate them and the savings.

Next time: Measure repeatedly before ordering or cutting, and if the number doesn't match expectations stop to ask why not.... and if it isn't working, consider stopping and returning it for store credit before doing anything that would keep you from being able to do so.